# get property from data variable in ajax jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, response

I try to get value of the variable what lay in response object(`data`  variable). Here is what I get when `console.log` whole `data`:

```
 {"comment_id":7,"view": ......
```

But when I try this to get  `comment_id` I getting `undefined`:

```
console.log(data['comment_id']); // undefined
console.log(data.comment_id); // undefined
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you check the type of the data? Was it a JSON or string ?

Comment: My gut feel is to do `console.log(JSON.parse(data).comment_id);` but without seeing more code, it's hard to tell

Comment: show the whole ajax request, or is going to be quite difficult knowing what is wrong

Comment: JSON.parse(data).comment_id) works, but I append dataType: json all works fine, thanks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to parse the JSON string you received in a JSON Object..

see $.parseJSON (if you have jQuery)

or else in pure JS

```
var mjsn = JSON.parse( your_json );
console.log(mjsn['key']);
// or 
console.log(mjsn.key);
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is from an ajax request your content type should be application/json to make that code work

if not parse it

> ```
> var json = JSON.parse(data);
> console.log(json.comment_id);
> ```